# How to make a pure CSS parellogram button using only 1 HTML tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a parellogram button like this:
https://codepen.io/brownerd/pen/vwfJA

I'm using an ecommerce system which unfortunately doesn't have a button component. It would be too much trouble to change the HTML of the button everywhere.

So how can I make a parellogram button with only one HTML like this `<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>`? The button should still have hover background color change.

Comment: on this codepen sample it used with an `<a>` tag so you dont have to use `<button>` component. You can create an `<a>` tag with a class.

or please be a little more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rely on pseudo element:

```css
.btn {
  padding:20px 30px;
  margin:10px;
  font-size:20px;
  border:none;
  background:none;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.btn::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:red;
  z-index:-1;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 blue;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 green;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#btn{
clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
padding:1rem;
transform:skew(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">button</button>
```